# How can i make a "Realtime" text change in div tag

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this sample code:

```
<textarea id="input" onkeydown="pressed()"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
function pressed()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input;
}
</script>
```

My problem is, if type something on the `input`, the script wont write it on the `output` immediately, it only does after I type another key.
So, is there anything that im not doing right?? Help pls

Comment: Try `onkeyup` so that it fires **after** you clicked button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) - then paste will also work

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = this.value;
})
```

```html
<textarea id="input" ></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `onkeydown` which triggers function pressed immediately, and `input` will equal to the value of input before you press.

Use onkeyup and it will work fine.